# How to intercept write using knockout mapping library

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Using `knockout` and `knockout mapping`, how can I intercept a write of a property?

What I've tried:

```
var data = { someBool: false, someOther: 'test value' };
var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
viewModel.someBool = ko.computed({
  read: function () { return this.someBool(); }
  , write: function (value) { this.someBool(value); $("#out").append("<br/>writing " + value); }
  , owner: this
});
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

I get the following error on loading the js: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'someBool'`

Live js here: http://jsbin.com/exokav/1/edit

Just trying to append to some $("#out") div I have for now, but later I'd like to write to `localStorage` in order to save state for the user. Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why don'y you just `subscribe` on the `someBool` property? http://jsbin.com/exokav/2/edit

Comment: maybe `subscribe` is what I'm looking for! How do I do that? I'm ultimately trying to achieve a way to update `localStorage` whenever the user toggles that checkbox, which is `data-bind`ed to the `.someBool`. more details in the post, "but later I'd like to..."

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to write to local storage when someBool changes, do this:

```
viewModel.someBool.subscribe(function(val) {
   // Write val to local storage.
});
```